# Sending post in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this submitHandler after a validation:

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    var data = $(form).toArray();
    var file_data = $('#firma').prop('files')[0];
    data.append('firma', file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: form.method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $(".modal-body").html(response)
            $("#modalDialog").modal();        
        }
    });
}
```

This code works perfectly but my problem is that it is redirecting to the controller that handle the function to insert the form data to the Database.

I was using this code to get the same result:

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    var data = new FormData();
    var file_data = $('#firma').prop('files')[0];
    data.append('firma', file_data);
    $.ajax({                
        url: form.action,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: form.method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response,e) {
            $(".modal-body").html(response)
            $("#modalDialog").modal();        
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, instead of using the `toArray()` function I was using new `FormData()`. This code does not redirect to the controller, instead it just shows the modal with the added HTML in the body, but it is just sending the file_data variable.

I tried replacing:

```
var data = new FormData();
```

with:

```
var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

And this works fine but I'm still redirected to the controller

This is my controller:

```
 public function enviarSolicitud(){

    //REVISAR SI EL ARCHIVO ES UNA IMAGEN DE CON EXTENSION VALIDA

    $allowed = array('gif', 'png', 'jepg', 'jpg');
    $filename = $_FILES['firma']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
        echo "El archivo no es válido, ingresa solamente imágenes";
    }else{

        //ERROR EN CASO QUE NO SE HAYA SUBIDO O NO SE DETECTE UN ARCHIVO

        $path = "admin/assets/global/img/stylos/firmas/";
        if (0 < $_FILES['firma']['error']){
            echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['firma']['error'] . '<br>';
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['firma']['tmp_name'], $path . $_FILES['firma']['name']);

            //INSERTAR LA INFORMACION DEL CLIENTE NUEVO EN LA BASE DE DATOS

            $data = array(
                'nombre' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
                'sexo' => $this->input->post('sexo'),
                'apellido_paterno' => $this->input->post('apellido_paterno'),
                'apellido_materno' => $this->input->post('apellido_materno'),
                'calle' => $this->input->post('calle'),
                'numero_ext' => $this->input->post('num_exterior'),
                'numero_int' => $this->input->post('num_interior'),
                'colonia' => $this->input->post('colonia'),
                'estado' => $this->input->post('estado'),
                'ciudad' => $this->input->post('ciudad'),
                'CP' => $this->input->post('c_postal'),
                'firma' => $path.$_FILES['firma']['name'],
                'tel_casa' => $this->input->post('tel'),
                'tel_celular' => $this->input->post('cel'),
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d'),
            );

            //OBTENER EL NUMERO DE CLIENTE PARA INSERTARLO EN LA TABLA DE AUTORIZACIONES

            $num_cliente = $this->CreditosModel->guardarSolicitud($data);

            $data = array(
                'num_cliente' => $num_cliente,
                'tipo' => 'Autorizar Crédito',
                'estatus' => 'P',
                'fecha_solicitud' => date('Y-m-d h:m:s')
            );
            $solicitud = $this->CreditosModel->solicitarAutorizacion($data);

            echo "La solicitud se ha procesado satisfactoriamente, favor de indicar al cliente que nos pondremos en contacto a la brevedad # de solicitud: <strong>".$solicitud."</strong>";

        }
    }        
}
```

I want to avoid the redirection and just show a modal with the `echo` string.

Comment: Inside of the ajax.success callback, have you tried `return;` to see if that stops the standard functionally, if that doesn't work get your controller to return a view instead of an action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have error in your script. Try

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var file_data = $('#firma')[0].files[0];
    data.append('firma', file_data);
    $.ajax({

        url: form.action,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: form.method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $(".modal-body").html(response)
            $("#modalDialog").modal();        
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, i can figure now my mistake, that works smoothly